# How to get write count of composite item writer?

Tags: spring-batch

How to know write count of each item writer of composite item writer?
Here is my composite item writer

```
<bean id="Writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter" scope="step">
<property name="classifier">
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.classify.BackToBackPatternClassifier">
     <property name="routerDelegate"><bean class="com.classifier.RecordKeeperClassifier" scope="prototype" />
     </property>
    <property name="matcherMap">
        <map>
          <entry key="abc" value-ref="ItemWriter1" />
          <entry key="xyz" value-ref="ItemWriter2" />
          <entry key="*" value-ref="errorItemWriter" />
        </map>
    </property>
    </bean>
</property>
</bean>
```

How to know no records with "abc" field  as a key in the  input file . I used footercallback listener and stepExecution.getWriteCount() method to know the writeCount , it is giving total count of inputs records I need only input records count with "abc" field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total count of written items is cumulative so you have to count item manually using a `ItemWriteListener` if you are using a built-in writer or - optionally - overriding `ItemWriter.write()` for a custom writer